# Recurrence Relations With Exponents

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Solve the following:

$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 2^{n-1} , a_0 = 3$$

Workings:

$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2} 2^n, a_o = 3$

$a_n^{(h)} = 2a_{n-1}$

The characteristic equation is:

$ch(x) = (x-2)$

$a_n^{(h)} = c(2)^n$

We have a particular solution of the form cn(2)^n.

$cn2^n = c(2)^{n-1} + 2^n$

$2cn = c + 2$

Now I'm not too sure if what I did so far is correct and I'm not sure on what to do next.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can always, if you want, get rid of the $2^{n}$ by subtracting $2a_n=4a_{n-1}+2^{n+2}$ and $a_{n+1}=2a_{n}+2^{n+2}$.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are doing at the end. You could do *variation of the constant* to get the solution for the in-homogeneous equation. Consider a solution of the form $a_n=c_n2^n$. Then $c_n2^n=c_{n-1}2^n+2^{n+1}$. Therefore $c_n=c_{n-1}+2$. So $C_n=2n+c_0$. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: @Pp. Yes that was what I was trying to do.

Comment: OP: A flat statement of the solution tells you "if what (you) did so far is correct" and "what to do next"? How is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your life easier look at 
$$
a_{k+1} = 2 a_k +2 ^k
$$
Divide through $2^k$ to get $b_{k+1} = \frac{a_{k+1}}{2^k}$. You have 
$$
b_{k+1}  = b_k + 1 \\
b_k = b_{k-1} + 1\\
\Delta b_{k+1} = \Delta b_k = \ldots  = \Delta b_1\\
$$
Now sum on both sides (telescoping sum on LHS) and plug in back expression for $a_n$.